# Several symbols -- check with box etc.

Tags: symbols

I have several symbols I don't know how to make. I have already gone to http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html to try to get answers, but I failed. Please help me.

[image] ☑☒

For the check with a box around, I use the following code, but it doesn't look as nice as the above one.

```
\fbox{$\surd$}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the first symbol, but [`symbols-a4`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) says that the package `wasysym` offers `\CheckedBox` and `\XBox`, which look like what you want for the latter two. Unfortunately the `\XBox` glyph isn't quite as calligraphic as the checked box you use, but still looks alright.

The `marvosym` package also offers `\Checkedbox` and `\Crossedbox`, which are calligraphic.

Do you know the name of the first symbol?

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you. yes, both wasysym and marvosym do have checked box and x box. i have looked through symbols-a4, but i missed them. for the first symbol, no name for it as i know. for civil engineer, it means the third grade of steel bar.

Comment: I was able to generate a fair approximation of your steel bar symbol using a modification of one of the examples given for composite symbols in the symbols-a4 document: `\newcommand{\steelbar}{\ooalign{$\upmodels$\raisebox{1.5pt}{\kern-5.70pt\tiny{$\bigcircle$}}}}`. This uses symbols found in the package `MnSymbol`. `\tiny\bigcircle` is a bit silly sounding but it gives decent line widths.

Comment: Here's what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/091Tv.png

Comment: thank you. it is really approximation except that the vertical lines are a little shorter. if the two vertical lines could be longer, it will be perfect. but it is better than having nothing.

Comment: Alternatively, it's a dirty hack but it works: create the glyph yourself in the vector editor of your choice, save as PDF and then use `\includegraphics{}` to insert it inline, with scaling and offsets to get it looking nice. Works well for editor's marks, but obviously wouldn't stand up to being transformed too heavily. Inkscape is a good choice of editor for this kind of thing.

Comment: yes, it is a way(not flexible), although it is a dirty hack.

Answer (score 2):

You have also the `pifont` package. From `symbols-a4` (a very fine document):

> The `pifont` dingbat package warrants special mention. Among other capabilities, `pifont` provides a LaTeX interface to the Zapf Dingbats font (one of the standard 35 PostScript fonts).

You can combine a box and checkmark to get a chechbox like with `wasysym`.

Comment: I've applied some markup (or rather markdown) to your answer. Click on "edited ... ago" to see how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from wasysym \checkbox and \XBox, already mentioned, there is AMS \boxtimes.